# Нужна помощь по работе с массивами

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет. Я новичок в PHP. Помогите пожалуйста с массивами, все прочитал, не смог найти то, что мне нужно, может просто не знал как это использовать.

Есть у меня вот такой вот массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PRODUCT_ID] => 610
            [OPTIONS] => Array
                (
                    [OPTION_1] => 1
                )

            [ADDS] => 
            [AMOUNT] => 6
            [SECTION_ID] => 62
            [HISTORY_PRICE] => 720
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [PRODUCT_ID] => 612
            [OPTIONS] => Array
                (
                    [OPTION_1] => 0
                )

            [ADDS] => 
            [AMOUNT] => 4
            [SECTION_ID] => 62
            [HISTORY_PRICE] => 720
        )

)
```

В нем есть опция **OPTION_1**. Как сделать так, что если **OPTION_1 = 1**, то происходит запись **PRODUCT_ID**?

Всем заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
  if ($item["OPTIONS"]["OPTION_1"] === 1)
    write($item["PRODUCT_ID"]);
}
```

Где `$data` ваш исходный массив